# How to query update in sql based on data from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 Tables.
As Example:

```
table1
ID, data_static1, name1
1      8          Muna
2      1          Andi
3      7          null

table2
ID, data_static2, name2
1       0         Aji
2       1         Andi
3       2         max
4       3         nadine
5       4         Rio
6       5         Panji
7       6         Eko
8       7         Pan
9       8         Muna
```

I want to update the column `name1` in table1 based on the largest ID in `table1` where `table1.data_static1` is the same as `table2.data_static2`.

I want the results as below

```
table1
ID, data_static1, name
1      8          Muna
2      1          Andi
3      7          Pan
```

I've tried the following code

```
mysql> UPDATE theDB.table1 SET name1=(SELECT name2 FROM table2 WHERE data_static2=(SELECT data_static1 From table1 WHERE ID IN(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table1))) WHERE table1.ID IN(SELECT MAX(table1.ID) FROM theDB.table1);
```

I get an error message

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to use a correlated subquery for this:

```
update table1 t1
set name1 = (
        select name2
        from table2 t2
        where t1.data_static1 = t2.data_static2
        order by id desc limit 1
        );
```

You can use JOIN too:

```
update table1 t1
join (
    select *
    from table2 t
    join (
        select data_static2,
            max(id) as id
        from table2
        group by data_static2
        ) t2 using (data_static2, id)
    ) t2 on t1.data_static1 = t2.data_static2
set t1.name1 = t2.name2;
```

Comment: @adjieq - Those are called aliases. Once defined, you can use them instead of the whole table name to refer to columns. They aid readability.